# Java synchronized list for loop

Tags: java, list, collections, for-loop, synchronized

Documentation on synchronizedList states that,

*It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:*

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
...
synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
    foo(i.next());
}
```

*Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.*

This seems pretty clear, but I just wanted to confirm that a for each loop is prohibited.  For example, I cannot do something like as follows right?

```
List<MyType> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(<MyType>));
...
synchronized(list){
    for(MyType m : list){
        foo(m);
        m.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would that be prohibited? The generated bytecode is pretty much the same. Foreach uses the iterator...

Comment: Seems that the synchronizedList only decorates the method calls with synchronized, but has limitations. Maybe the designers should have decorated the iterator method as well, and return a synchronized iterator. The for is on the language and cannot be decorated so easily XD:

Comment: Check this link https://programmerzdojo.com/java-tutorials/how-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java/ it might help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you can - your enhanced for loop is basically the same as your code which explicitly uses the iterator. It boils down to the same code - it's just calling `iterator()` and then alternating between `next()` and `hasNext()` calls.

Comment: if we delete item from iterator, while using hasNext()/next() it is ok. but if we delete some item from the list when we iterate though it by for(int : list) loop - it will throw ConcurentModificationException. So it is not same in this context.

Comment: @ses: But the code given doesn't use `remove`. An enhanced for loop does use the iterator (for non-arrays) - but that doesn't mean that you can do everything with an enhanced for loop that you could do with the iterator directly.

Comment: That's... Could you look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742763/using-iterator-over-for-loop-in-concurrent-java-app

Answer (score 1):

You can do that.  The foreach loop compiles to (nearly) the same bytecode as the while loop.  The keys are:

1. You synchronize the block around the loop because the list may change while you are iterating over it.
2. You use the list as the object that you are synchronizing on, since the implementation of this class locks on itself (through synchronized methods).

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you might want to consider using immutability rather than synchonization.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, the only problem I see here is a performance issue, if your method `dosomething()` or `foo(m)` are costly to execute, you will have a performance cost. The size of your collection is also important to take in account while looping in a synchronized block, due to the fact that, when a thread acquire the lock, while in the synchronized block, looping in a huge collection will push other threads to wait.

Comment: Some formatting, a few more words and it actually could be an answer ;]