# Using iterator over for-loop in concurrent java app

Tags: java, concurrency

`class Nodes` has `getNodes()` method, which is `not synchronized`. But `List<Node> nodes` - `is synchronized`. Many threads could be connected to it, changing `nodes` in it.

Like this:

```
class Nodes {
 List<Node> nodes = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Node>() );

 public List<Nodes> getNodes() { return nodes; }
 ...
}
```

Client code:

```
Nodes nodes;

synchronized(nodes) {

 for(Node node: nodes.getNodes()) {
  ...
 }

}
```

I do not have interrogation tests for that, but:

Should I use `while(iterator.hasNext()) { var = iterator.next() }` instead of for-loop ?

Because I know that when I try to delete `nodes.remove(node)` inside for-loop it fails with `ConcurentModificationException`.

---

**EDIT:** (related issue)

If iterator is good stuff to use, then having this code (client code):

```
Iterator<Node> iter = nodes.getNodes().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {  // line 1
    Node node = iter.next();  // line 2
}
```

It is not safe anyway:

```
 1. thread1 goes to line 1, hoping that now iter would return him next() value. 
 2. but at that moment thread2 delete that value.
 3. thread1 has Exception and fails.
```

Does it mean that I should do locking on client side anyway. This is what I don't want to do.

One of the solutions I have:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            
    try {
       Node node = iter.next();
       ...
                  
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {continue;}  // handle exception - do more try
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Answer for my case was: to use **CopyOnWriteArrayList**. I can even stay with `for-loop` with it.

But another option: Just return client a copy of the list to let them know whatever they want with it. Because it is kind of strange (inconsistent) providing 'snapshot iterator' AND real data in the list at the same time.

Comment: It is always recommended to use Iterator in multi-threaded environment..

Comment: @Ankur Can you clarify your comment? Enhanced for does use an iterator behind the scenes.

Comment: Also note that `ConcurrentModificationException` isn't specifically related to multi-threading.

Comment: "It is always recommended to use Iterator in multi-threaded environment" What is the basis of this comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an iterator like you have suggest, but instead of doing a `nodes.delete()` (which is really a `nodes.remove(...)` ) you should instead do `iterator.remove()`

You have updated your question. Here's an updated answer addressing the 'atomicity' of the iterator. If you want your iterator to have a 'snapshot' of the values at the time it (the iterator) was created, then you can use the Concurrent set of collections in java.util.concurrent:  like [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: I've fixed that. Thx. I add more EDIT.

Comment: It' interesting. Do you think it is much better than catching NoSuchElementException in while loop? It seem then no need to do copy every time when do read, and no need to use new structure, confusing people by that.

Comment: Probably not.. I feel that that exception handling is not thread safe. Meaning that I can wait/do repeating for something that is not real.

Comment: But another option: Just return to client a copy of the list to let them know whatever they want with it. Because it is kind of strange (inconsistent) providing 'snapshot iterator' AND real data in the list at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

> Iterator.remove is the *only* safe way to modify a collection during iteration

Source: [The Collection Interface tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

Answer (score 0):

What is even better:

To use:

```
private List<Node> defensiveCopyNodeList() {
    List<Node> nodesListCopy = Lists.newLinkedList();
    synchronized (nodesList) {
        nodesListCopy = ImmutableList.copyOf(nodesList);  // Google [Guava lib][1]
    }
    return  nodesListCopy;
}
```

Then in getter:

```
public List<Node> getNodes() {
      return  defensiveCopyNodeList();
}
```

Then it allows us to use safely **not only iterator** but and **data itself**.